# NIC still active after shutdown and removal of power supply

Tags: shutdown, network-adapter, wake-on-lan, motherboard

The NIC on the motherboard of one of my computers continues to communicate over the wire even **after shut down** and the **removal of the computer's power source**!

Apparent communication continues after removing the mains power to the computer.
If I remove the RJ-45 plug the link beat disappears as well as any activity. If I re-insert the plug the activity begins again!

I would appreciate any feedback from others who can help. Particularly I would like to find out if others have this problem and what can be done to repair it or at least discover what is happening (or possibly being transmitted).

- NIC is a LAN-based motherboard component.
- Motherboard is an **Intel Model DP67BA with a i7 3770K CPU**.
- I tried to examine the activity with Wireshark, but it seems that it cannot 'see' this traffic although I have no filter set and should see all data on the wire.
- The activity is not a link beat indication as I see the packet count rise on my router. Also the activity is random and intermittent.
- I turned off WOL (wake on LAN) function in BIOS from the very beginning (before setting up the node). WOL function is also turned off in the driver (running Windows 7 Ultimate).
- I will be checking this with other (and older) protocol analyzers to see if I get some answers. I will post my findings here, when I have something to report.

PS: I have seen the similar post from last year, but my problem is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  The link light is receiving power from the switch its connected to.  The "activity" is just the switch trying to determine if there is something on the other end to communicate with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however if I later connect the NIC to the switch no such activity is apparent. Only after powering the system does this continue.

Comment: Another thing: if what you say is true, then why is the router behaving this way with only that particular node?

Comment: if the machine is powered off before you connect it to the switch, then there will be no activity, since there is nothing there.  If the machine was on when connected to the switch and then powered off, the switch will check to see if it comes back online.

Comment: Thanks Keltari, that is all very good, but I found my answer. I had to disable the AMT in BIOS and in Windows 7.